# Selecting from list like array (without name by number)

Tags: ls

After I `ls` and see the list, is there anyway to process a document without typing its name?

For example instead of typing `rm damnSoLongFileName`, can I type something like `rm [1]`?

I mean is there anyway to use `ls` like array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a one liner:

```
for something in $( ls );do echo $something;done
```

Or using `select`:

```
select item in $( ls );do echo $item;done
```

You could replace `echo` with `rm` and it would remove the item that you selected. You could then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>  to stop the loop.

Output:

```
bob@bob-p7-1298c:~$ select item in $( ls );do echo $item;done
1) adifferentlikethis    6) Documents       11) initramfs       16) MESVG20.xlsx    21) out.png     26) racket      31) t~          36) Untitled        41) VMs
2) bash_speakit      7) Downloads       12) irssi_log       17) MLGVG17.xlsx    22) output.mp3      27) run.py      32) Templates       37) Document
3) color_img.jpg     8) ec2         13) likethis        18) MLRVG17.xlsx    23) php5        28) run.sh      33) test        38) 1
4) DATES         9) examples.desktop    14) lpr         19) Music       24) Pictures        29) space.txt       34) t.sh        39) Videos
5) Desktop      10) grub.iso        15) MEEVG19.xlsx    20) nano.save       25) Public      30) t           35) Untitled-2.pd   40) VirtualBox
#?
```

I then enter a number and it will echo it back to me.

```
#? 2
bash_speakit
```

Another Possibility:

```
thearray=( $(ls) )
echo "${thearray[2]}"
```

Output:

```
color_img.jpg
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use tab-completion for long filenames. For your example type something like `rm damn<TAB>`.

Answer (score 1):

From the "I mean is there anyway to use ls like array?" part I would assume that the question is about simply streaming the ls results into some other command thus I'm replying with a link to [Xargs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs) and a simple example usage of it:

```
find -name '*.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

Check `man find` for more information about how to find, filter and stream the results using `find` command and `man xargs` for a full manual about xargs. The above example is a simple classic case of `-print0 + -0` combination of arguments between the two using pipe.

Answer (score 0):

No doubt unorthodox, but if you copy the script below into an empty file, save it as `ls_2` in `~/bin`, make it executable, and run it by the command (from anywhere):

```
ls_2
```

it will show a list like:

```
jacob@jacob-System-Product-Name:~/Bureaublad/all kinds of crap$ ls_2
1. nog te doen.odt
2. otto
3. GW_site_werkmap
4. sanel
5. blacklist.2
6. sanel_edited
7. sanel_gigue.mp3
8. Sprachmemo_011[1].m4a
9. PRG001
10. crap

please enter numbers to remove (separated by a comma): 1,3,5
```

Just enter the numbers and the items (both directories and files) will be removed.

Like the "real" ls command, it can be run from the current directory (just `ls_2`) or with a directory as argument (`ls_2 /path/to/directory`).

#### The script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import shutil
import sys

try:
    currdir = sys.argv[1]
except IndexError:
    currdir = os.getcwd()

items = os.listdir(currdir)
for i in range(len(items)):
    print(str(i+1)+".", items[i])

remove = input("\nplease enter numbers to remove (separated by a comma): ")
indices = [int(it) for it in remove.split(",")]
for i in indices:
    file = currdir+"/"+items[i-1]
    try:
        os.remove(file)
    except IsADirectoryError:
        shutil.rmtree(file)
```

Comment: this requires non standard interpreter

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ There is no Ubuntu without python.

Comment: that does not mean that user will use it as a shell

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ ??? python will be called anyway, since it is executable and in the shebang. the user will not be bothered to do anything.

Comment: I means that there are systems without python but with bash/ksh, and the asker gives the example in bash/ksh

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ Since this is Ask*Ubuntu* we may assume python is installed, else the system is broken.

Comment: where is that condition described?

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ which condition? That python is installed? Try for yourself (if you are using Ubuntu) and remove python.

Comment: I'am able to remove python, a fortiori if I use just a console linux

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ Come on man, you are looking for a faint argument in a faint discussion. Feel free to remove python. Ubuntu comes with. Even in the weird situation that python would not be installed, the worst thing that could happen is that it doesn't work.

Comment: @JacobVlijm let suppose so... `for a faint argument in a faint discussion.`